# What data structure/algorithm to use to compute similarity between input sequence and a database of stored sequences?

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, sequence, bioinformatics, string-comparison

By this question, I mean if I have an input sequence `abchytreq` and a database / data structure containing `jbohytbbq`, I would compare the two elements pairwise to get a match of 5/9, or 55%, because of the pairs (`b-b`, `hyt-hyt`, `q-q`). Each sequence additionally needs to be linked to another object (but I don't think this will be hard to do). The sequence does not necessarily need to be a string.

The maximum number of elements in the sequence is about 100. This is easy to do when the database/datastructure has only one or a few sequences to compare to, but **I need to compare the input sequence to over 100000 (mostly) unique sequences**, and then return a certain number of the most similar previously stored data matches. Additionally, each element of the sequence could have a different weighting. Back to the first example: if the first input element was weighted double, `abchytreq` would only be a 50% match to `jbohytbbq`.

I was thinking of using [BLAST](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BLAST) and creating a little hack as needed to account for any weighting, but I figured that might be a little bit overkill. What do you think?

One more thing. Like I said, comparison needs to be *pairwise*, e.g. `abcdefg` would be a zero percent match to `bcdefgh`.

Answer (score 1):

A modified Edit Distance algorithm with weightings for character positions could help.

https://www.biostars.org/p/11863/

Multiply the resulting distance matrix with a matrix of weights for character positions/

Comment: Yes, I know that... but this is an unacceptable by itself when comparing an input against over 100,000 stored sequences. You would have to compare each individually and that takes too much time for the user to wait for, and is too computationally expensive

Comment: A parallel version of edit distance here http://blog.faroo.com/2015/03/24/fast-approximate-string-matching-with-large-edit-distances/

Comment: That seems to be very similar to what I needed, thanks! I'll read up on it. I was thinking of using Tries but didn't know how to deal with interruptions in the middle of a sequence

Answer (score 1):

I'm not entirely clear on the question; for instance, would you return all matches of 90% or better, regardless of how many or few there are, or would you return the best 10% of the input, even if some of them match only 50%? Here are a couple of suggestions:

First: Do you know the story of the wise bachelor? The foolish bachelor makes a list of requirements for his mate --- slender, not blonde (Mom was blonde, and he hates her), high IQ, rich, good cook, loves horses, etc --- then spends his life considering one mate after another, rejecting each for failing one of his requirements, and dies unfulfilled. The wise bachelor considers that he will meet 100 marriageable women in his life, examines the first sqrt(100) = 10 of them, then marries the next mate with a better score than the best of the first ten; she might not be perfect, but she's good enough. There's some theorem of statistics that says the square root of the population size is the right cutoff, but I don't know what it's called.

Second: I suppose that you have a scoring function that tells you exactly which of two dictionary words is the better match to the target, but is expensive to compute. Perhaps you can find a partial scoring function that is easy to compute and would allow you to quickly scan the dictionary, discarding those inputs that are unlikely to be winners, and then apply your total scoring function only to that subset of the dictionary that passed the partial scoring function. You'll have to define the partial scoring function based on your needs. For instance, you might want to apply your total scoring function to only the first five characters of the target and the dictionary word; if that doesn't eliminate enough of the dictionary, increase to ten characters on each side.